# Ruby on Rails Hosted Backend Not Saving Sessions When Logging In

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, session-storage

So, I've hosted a completed backend Rails 7 application to Heroku, but for some reason, my frontend fetch requests are not responding the same way they did when I hosted the backend on my local storage. The session is not being saved when I log in. To simplify things, I created a very basic React frontend that just makes simple fetch requests to the backend to sign up, log in, signout, and check if I'm logged in.This works perfectly fine when my backend is hosted locally, but completely breaks down when I try to use the deployed version.

My relevant backend routes:

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"
  resources :users, only: [:create, :show, :index]
  resources :products, only: [:create, :show, :index, :destroy]
  
  post '/signup',         to: 'users#create'
  post '/login',    to: 'sessions#create'
  get '/logged_in', to: 'sessions#is_logged_in?'
  delete '/logout',   to: 'sessions#destroy'

end
```

My helper functions stored in applications controller:

```html
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
    helper_method :login!, :logged_in?, :current_user, :authorized_user?, :logout!, :set_user
        
    def login!
          session[:user_id] = @user.id
    end
    def logged_in?
          !!session[:user_id]
    end
    def current_user
          @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end
    def authorized_user?
           @user == current_user
    end
    def logout!
        session.clear
    end
    def set_user
        @user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    end
end
```

My sessions controller:

```html
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @user = User.find_by(username: session_params[:username])
      
        if @user && @user.authenticate(session_params[:password])
          login!
          render json: {
            logged_in: true,
            user: @user
          }
        else
          render json: { 
            status: 401,
            errors: ['Incorrect username or password, please try again.']
          }
        end
    end
    def is_logged_in?
        if logged_in? && current_user
          render json: {
            logged_in: true,
            user: current_user
          }
        else
          render json: {
            logged_in: false,
            message: 'no such user'
          }
        end
    end
    def destroy
          logout!
          render json: {
            status: 200,
            logged_out: true
          }
    end
    private
    def session_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password)
    end
end
```

My users controller:

```html
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @users = User.all
           if @users
              render json: {
              users: @users
           }
          else
              render json: {
              status: 500,
              errors: ['no users found']
          }
         end
    end

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
            if @user
                render json: {
                user: @user
            }
            else
                render json: {
                status: 500,
                errors: ['user not found']
                }
            end
        end
        
    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
            if @user.save
                login!  
                render json: {
                status: :created,
                user: @user
            }
            else 
                render json: {
                status: 500,
                errors: @user.errors.full_messages
            }
            end
    end

    private


        
        def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation)
        end
end
```

I have rack-cors installed and the middleware set up with the correct origins, and I'm not running into any CORS errors.

Checking the sources tab of developer tools tells me nothing is stored in my sessions storage, though I do have things stored as cookies.[image: Local storage and sessions storage are empty]

Please let me know what the problem is, or if you need any more information.

The backend is currently deployed at: https://floating-journey-28678.herokuapp.com.

Thank you so much.

EDIT: Yes, the backend is being called. Here's the fetch requests for my basic react frontend.I'm just console logging the results from the promise.

```html
import React from 'react';
import config from '../baseUrl';
const Test = () => {
    function handleLoggedInClick(){
        fetch(`${config.baseUrl}/logged_in`).then((r) => {
            r.json().then(results=>{
             console.log(results);
             })
            })
    }
    function handleSignupClick(){

        fetch(`${config.baseUrl}/signup`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({user: {
                "username": "newroy5",
                "password": "newpass",
                password_confirmation: "newpass",
      
            }}),
          })
            .then((r) => {
            if (r.ok) {
              console.log(r.json(), "successfully created account and logged in apparently")
            } else {
              console.log("error creating account");
            }
          })
    }
    function handleLoginClick(){
        fetch(`${config.baseUrl}/login`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({user: {
                "username": "newroy5",
                "password": "newpass"
      
            }}),
          })
            .then((r) => {
            if (r.ok) {
              console.log(r.json(), "successfully logged in apparently")
            } else {
              console.log("error signing in");
            }
          })
    }
    function handleSignoutClick(){
        fetch(`${config.baseUrl}/logout`, { method: "DELETE"}).then((r) => {
            if (r.ok) {
               console.log(r.json())
            }
          })
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={()=>handleLoggedInClick()}>am i logged in</button>
            <button onClick={()=>handleLoginClick()}>login</button>
            <button onClick={()=>handleSignupClick()}>signup</button>
            <button onClick={()=>handleSignoutClick()}>signout</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Test;
```

This is what the console log looks like after I

1. check if logged in
2. signup (creates a new account and saves it to the database, but it's just the login that's not working)
3. check if logged in again (it says I'm not, though I should be)
4. Try to login with new account details (doesn't work)
5. check if logged in AGAIN (it says I'm not, though I should be)

[image]
As you can see, there are no CORS errors, or any other errors besides the basic react ones at the top which shouldn't have anything to do with this.

This is what the heroku logs look like:

[image]

```html
2023-05-04T14:14:01.185733+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logged_in" host=floating-journey-28678.herokuapp.com request_id=45cde821-1591-4400-99ce-5cff60e5752e fwd="47.36.48.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=1553 protocol=https
2023-05-04T14:14:05.991960+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-05-04T14:14:05.991889 #2]  INFO -- : [bc0ef462-c09a-416a-b08c-c3acb577ce6a] Started POST "/signup" for 47.36.48.112 at 2023-05-04 14:14:05 +0000
2023-05-04T14:14:05.992698+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-05-04T14:14:05.992654 #2]  INFO -- : [bc0ef462-c09a-416a-b08c-c3acb577ce6a] Processing by UsersController#create as */*
2023-05-04T14:14:05.992721+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-05-04T14:14:05.992701 #2]  INFO -- : [bc0ef462-c09a-416a-b08c-c3acb577ce6a]   Parameters: {"user"=>{"username"=>"newroy6", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
2023-05-04T14:14:06.230210+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-05-04T14:14:06.230146 #2]  INFO -- : [bc0ef462-c09a-416a-b08c-c3acb577ce6a] Completed 200 OK in 237ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 5.5ms | Allocations: 709)
2023-05-04T14:14:06.230614+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/signup" host=floating-journey-28678.herokuapp.com request_id=bc0ef462-c09a-416a-b08c-c3acb577ce6a fwd="47.36.48.112" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=241ms status=200 bytes=1917 protocol=https
2023-05-04T14:14:07.370561+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logged_in" host=floating-journey-28678.herokuapp.com request_id=109bc4ad-b3d7-4b24-a08a-817879101ca0 fwd="47.36.48.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=1551 protocol=https
2023-05-04T14:14:07.368374+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-05-04T14:14:07.368309 #2]  INFO -- : [109bc4ad-b3d7-4b24-a08a-817879101ca0] Started GET "/logged_in" for 47.36.48.112 at 2023-05-04 14:14:07 +0000
2023-05-04T14:14:07.369433+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-05-04T14:14:07.369391 #2]  INFO -- : [109bc4ad-b3d7-4b24-a08a-817879101ca0] Processing by SessionsController#is_logged_in? as */*
2023-05-04T14:14:07.370022+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-05-04T14:14:07.369985 #2]  INFO -- : [109bc4ad-b3d7-4b24-a08a-817879101ca0] Completed 200 OK in 0ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 94)
2023-05-04T14:14:08.474406+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/login" host=floating-journey-28678.herokuapp.com request_id=edc432df-5a49-4798-8e43-c1228029f13c fwd="47.36.48.112" dyno=web.1 connect=16ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=346 protocol=https
2023-05-04T14:14:08.510412+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-05-04T14:14:08.510335 #2]  INFO -- : [8179c87b-7ed7-4eb2-93c4-2650511d907f] Started POST "/login" for 47.36.48.112 at 2023-05-04 14:14:08 +0000
2023-05-04T14:14:08.511475+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-05-04T14:14:08.511421 #2]  INFO -- : [8179c87b-7ed7-4eb2-93c4-2650511d907f] Processing by SessionsController#create as */*
2023-05-04T14:14:08.511509+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-05-04T14:14:08.511484 #2]  INFO -- : [8179c87b-7ed7-4eb2-93c4-2650511d907f]   Parameters: {"user"=>{"username"=>"newroy6", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "session"=>{"user"=>{"username"=>"newroy6", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}
2023-05-04T14:14:08.750281+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-05-04T14:14:08.750193 #2]  INFO -- : [8179c87b-7ed7-4eb2-93c4-2650511d907f] Completed 200 OK in 239ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms | Allocations: 415)
2023-05-04T14:14:08.751041+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/login" host=floating-journey-28678.herokuapp.com request_id=8179c87b-7ed7-4eb2-93c4-2650511d907f fwd="47.36.48.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=242ms status=200 bytes=1941 protocol=https
2023-05-04T14:14:09.892031+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logged_in" host=floating-journey-28678.herokuapp.com request_id=9696291b-96ee-4a72-bf12-107f4d0b0b6e fwd="47.36.48.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=1571 protocol=https
2023-05-04T14:14:09.890722+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-05-04T14:14:09.890659 #2]  INFO -- : [9696291b-96ee-4a72-bf12-107f4d0b0b6e] Started GET "/logged_in" for 47.36.48.112 at 2023-05-04 14:14:09 +0000
2023-05-04T14:14:09.891644+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-05-04T14:14:09.891601 #2]  INFO -- : [9696291b-96ee-4a72-bf12-107f4d0b0b6e] Processing by SessionsController#is_logged_in? as */*
2023-05-04T14:14:09.891951+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-05-04T14:14:09.891925 #2]  INFO -- : [9696291b-96ee-4a72-bf12-107f4d0b0b6e] Completed 200 OK in 0ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 94)
```

Comment: Is the backend even being called? What do you see in the logs?

Comment: @dbugger yes, I'm calling the backend. I just added the mini frontend I'm using to test it, the console outputs, and the corresponding heroku logs. There doesn't seem to be anything out of the ordinary, and once again it works when deployed locally, so I'm really at a loss.

Comment: This looks like an issue on the React side -- I see three {logged_in: false, message: "no such user"} entries, two after you supposedly logged in. Seems you the react code is not doing what you expect after the login to rails.

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of code and exceptions. They are not searchable or copyable and you're forcing anyone wanting to spend time helping you to have to retype the code which dissuades answers (you do want an actual answer to your question, right?). Please update the question and add any relevant code as text. Delimit the code blocks by four backticks or using the button on the editor window which indents the code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @dbugger all I'm doing on the react end is console logging the results of calling "/logged-in" to the backend, so I really doubt it's a problem with my React code.